# 9patch drawable as RelativeLayout background issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got RelativeLayout as a header in Activity and I want it to have 9.png drawable as a background. 
Here is drawable:

[image]

What I receive:

[image]

As you can see - there is extra spacing.

Here I use RGB color as a backgroud(and how I want it look with 9patch):

[image]

Is it me doing something funny or it's normal for 9patch to look like that?

**UPDATED WITH CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <--THIS IS IT-->
    android:background="@drawable/cap">
    <--THIS IS IT-->
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnSearchMainReset"
      android:text="@string/btnSearchMainReset_text"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
  </RelativeLayout>
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/relativeTop">
  <RelativeLayout
      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
      android:paddingRight="5dp"
      android:layout_below="@id/relativeTop"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#FFFFFF">
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchMainSearch"
        android:text="@string/btnSearchMainSearch_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:width="200dp" 
      /> 
      <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeMain"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnSearchMainSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <-- MULTIPLE VIEWS HERE -->
      </RelativeLayout>
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchMainSearchLow"
        android:text="@string/btnSearchMainSearch_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@@id/relativeMain"
        android:width="200dp" 
      /> 
  </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the code from your layout xml

Comment: Layout looks fine. I definitively think it's a NinePatch matter.

Comment: Yeah, OcuS' example is how to do it. Your problem is the drop shadow extending out. You just can't see it since it's over a black background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This how your image should look if you want no extra spacing.

[image: image.9.png]

Have a look at android documentation on [Nine Patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) ; especially be careful about strechable area and padding box. The image defines itself the padding using data pixels given on right and top edges.

Nine Patch is all about logic and graphical programing, which can be very confusing at the beginning...

Comment: with a gradient it is going to get distorted on some devices if you make it stretch more than 1 pixel vertically. There is a "Show Bad Patches" button in the draw9patch app that will highlight this for you. Of course if you only stretch one pixel then then the center of your view is only going to have 1 color and it will gradient fade only on the edges.